# Wake On LAN behaviour - works intermittently

Tags: networking, power-management, wake-on-lan

When I send WoL packets over my network the specified boxes tend to wake up the first time I send the packet each day, but if I turn the box off then subsequent WoL packets tend to be unsuccessful.

Is Wake on LAN designed to have a "cool-off" period or something? Or is there another reason for this?

Thanks,
Rick

Comment: As far as I know, WOL does need a network/router that supports it (as the magic packet needs to be sent to the right subnet in which the MAC address can be found). But since the first packet works, I guess the router is not the culprit. Still, maybe others can provide better help when knowing what router is used?

Comment: Some more info or clarification would help. What is the box you are turning off? What is the network topology you have?